# Showing only product which are not assigned in sub category in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have made ability main category to have sub-category. So far everything work great except when I add product in some sub-category this product is also visible in main category.

How to show the product only on sub-category and if product isn't assigned to sub-category to show it in main category?

Here is how I select and show products

```
public function showCategoryInfo($categoryId) {
    /** @var Product $product */

    $category = Categories::with('products')->findOrFail( $categoryId );
        return View::make('site.single_category', [
            'category' => $category
        ]);
}
```

So I've tried to add `where` clause in query which select categories and products in categories but the problem is that this column isn't in `categories` table but in `products`

```
$category = Categories::with('products')->where('sub_cat_id', 0)->findOrFail( $categoryId );
```

Product which doesn't have sub-category by default are `sub_cat_id = 0`

This is my `Categories` model

```
protected $table = 'category';
protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';

public $timestamps = false;

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Product', 'category_id');
} 
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('SubCategories', 'category_id');
}
```

And `Product` model

```
protected $table = 'products';
protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Categories', 'category_id');
}
```